# The MVC model and methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to wrap my head around the MVC model, so I'm wondering how to implement something in it.

I have a resource that has different properties. I also have a controller from it that I set up from scaffolding, like new, show etc.

The way I understand it is that I am supposed to define in the controller what things are available for my view to use. Going from that, what I want to do is make a method and use it in the show view.

I want to make a `.find` method that checks all the values of a particular property of my resource, e.g. I have  a resources named `users` with a property of region. When I view a users profile page I want an area to list all users in the same region as the current profile.

Where do I define this method? Is it in the controller or the model, and then how do I call it properly in the view? Currently there is already code in the `show` method in the controller, and, if I'm correct, I understand that the last line of the code executes, or prints out in the view, so how do I include that in it? Wouldn't it conflict?

I'm sure I'm not understanding something but I would just like some guidance.

Comment: You'll want to investigate model relationships.  Models hold data.  Controllers control data flows.  Views display data.

Comment: so where exactly would i create this method? by the soun dof it it should be in the controller, is that right?

Comment: No. Actually he's wrong. Models don't hold data. Models hold the Method. The database (conveniently enough) holds the data. Models hold the method that the data is used, controller control the flow of that data, and the database holds the data itself. You should probably go through some of the rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: You probably want two models.  One for users, and one for regions (since I assume multiple users can belong to the same region, otherwise what would be the point).  Tying them together would be an `association`.  Read more here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @mysticcola yeah, technically that's correct.  I was over-simplifying given the context since this isn't a "train someone in MVC" site. :)

Comment: thanks guys suprisingly that actually really cleared up, can you point me in the right direction of how to use the find method by column name? i cannot find what im looking for,

Comment: @Donovan NOW you're talking! Let's start a "train someone in MVC" site! :)

Comment: user when you create a model you get to define the db columns associated with that model. Once you've migrated those into the actual database, you can use the model to determine which columns are accessible.

Answer (score 2):

As Donovan mentioned in the comment, you may need two models - **User** and **Region** and an association between them to handle their queries, here is an example:

First of all, your `users` table need a `region_id` column to associate the region where the user belongs to.

db/migrates/20131227153435_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.belongs_to :region
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

And add associations in your **User** and **Region** models.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  # ...
end
```

app/models/region.rb

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  # ...
end
```

Then you can get what you want in your controllers.

```
user = User.find(1) # find the user with id = 1
user.region # to get the user's region

region = Region.find(1) # find the region with id = 1
region.users # to get all users who are in this region
```

Please reference [Rails Guides Guidelines - Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a resource named `resourceone`.

The logic for fetching the data from database ( via a model ) will go to this file:

`app/controllers/resourceone_controller.rb`

This would look something like this

```
class ResourceoneController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @resourceones = Resourceone.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @resourceones }
    end
  end
end
```

Now your view will be in this file:

`app/views/resourceone/index.html.erb`

This is where you can write your HTML and embed some ruby code in erb tags.

Now in your case you need to make a relationship between your resource and a user. So once you do that, in the controller, you can do:

```
@user = User.find(user_id)
@resourceones = Resourceone.where(user: @user)
```

All the instance variables like `@user` and `@resourceones` are automatically available in the views, so you can just use them to render the UI.

For any more specific API, you may want to visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 0):

Sibevans answer is the best way to handle this if you are working with associations, but if you're working with an existing table and region happens to be an attribute of your User model which I suspect is the case, I would suggest building your find method within the user model as an `instance method`, preferably with a descriptive method name that explains what it is doing. You can later create an alias to that `instance method` if you prefer:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def find_all_users_belonging_to_same_region
    User.where(:region => self.region)
  end

  alias :find_region :find_all_users_belonging_to_same_region

end
```

Note this returns an ActiveRecord Relation and not an array. If you prefer an array you could put a `.all` on the end like this:

`User.where(:region => self.region).all` which is the equivalent of

`User.find_all_by_region(self.region)`

That being said, there are benefits to using an ActiveRecord Relation in that you could later chain additional database methods on that method, such as

```
my_user.find_all_users_belonging_to_same_region.where("income > ?", 50000)
```

Note, since find is a reserved word in ActiveRecord, I would advise not using it as the name of your method if it is to go in the model.

Then from within your controller, you could define an `action` called find, which works on the instance of the user you have by way of params.

**get users/71/find**

would pass the user id 71 to the params hash in your controller and you can access your method on that object as follows:

```
def find
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @users_in_region = @user.find_all_users_belonging_to_same_region
end
```

And those two instance variables you just created in your controller, one being your current user, and the second being your array or ActiveRecord Relation of users belonging to the region would all be available objects to use in your view.